# Move text before delimiter to the end of the line

Tags: sed, move, delimiter

I have a file with output like this:

```
MIKE;123456
JOHN-HELPER;654321
SAM.SMITH;182364
```

I need everything before the delimiter to move to the end of the line, so it'll look like this:

```
123456;MIKE
654321;JOHN-HELPER
182364;SAM.SMITH
```

Struggling it work it out with `sed`... any ideas?

Answer (score 2):

Like this, for example:

```
$ sed -r 's/([^;]*);(.*)/\2;\1/' a
123456;MIKE
654321;JOHN-HELPER
182364;SAM.SMITH
```

It "catches" two groups: everything before `;` and then the rest. Next step is to print these blocks the other way round: `\2;\1`.

Or with `awk`:

```
$ awk -F";" '{print $2";"$1}' a
123456;MIKE
654321;JOHN-HELPER
182364;SAM.SMITH
```

It sets `;` as field delimiter and then prints the fields the other way round.